# Sensor Connection: DIN 43650 vs M12

Tags: sensor, connector, pressure

Preface, I'm a plant engineer and my background is mechanical engineering. My current project requires me to find some pressure sensors for my compressed air lines and this is a pretty new territory for me. These sensors will be located in a dry room, same room as our compressors and PLC; so no running long wires or having to worry about water. I'm pretty set with the specifications of the sensors, now what I'm stuck with is choosing between two connection types. As an ME I'm not terribly familiar with the different connection types.

The site I'm looking at offers two connectors:

- a DIN 43650 (DIN 175301-803C) connector

[image: DIN 43651]

- an M12 Connector

[image]

So my questions are:

1. What would be the advantages/disadvantages of both? From what I've found, M12 is better for harsher environments, like from a washdown; but other sites mention that the DIN connector is also capable of sealing from water. It also seems to me that M12 is more secure due to screw connection. How does the DIN connector keeps itself secure?
2. For my application, does it matter which one I choose?
3. Are there any effects to the electrical signal between the sensor and my PLC when choosing one connector to another? I'm using current to sense the pressure.
4. (bonus) What other connection options are commonly used among electrical engineers for connecting small sensors and actuators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... the DIN connector is also capable of sealing from water.

The compressible cable gland waterproofs the cable entry. The square gasket waterproofs the electrical terminals.

> It also seems to me that M12 is more secure due to screw connection. How does the DIN connector keeps itself secure?

The long screw visible in your photo goes through a central hole in the rear of the shell and into the threaded insert in the transducer. It's good.

> For my application, does it matter which one I choose?

Probably not. The DIN is less fiddly to wire up. You might consider calibration and what type of leads you or your calibration contractor have to hand but either is easily fabricated.

> Are there any effects to the electrical signal between the sensor and my PLC when choosing one connector to another? I'm using current to sense the pressure.

No.

> What other connection options are commonly used among electrical engineers for connecting small sensors and actuators?

The M8 version of the circular connector is most common. Your two and the M8 are the most popular.